# 3D rotation minimizing sum of squared distance between lines: closed-form formula?

Tags: geometry

I have two set of 3D lines $(P_i, \mathbf{m}_i)_n$ and $(Q_i, \mathbf{n}_i)_n$ defined here by a point and a direction vector. I want to find the rotation and translation that minimize the sum of squared distance between those lines,

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^n d^2(P_i, \mathbf{m}_i, Q'_i, \mathbf{n}'_i),
\end{eqnarray}

where
\begin{eqnarray}
Q'_i &=& R.Q_i + t\,,\\
\mathbf{n}'_i &=& R.\mathbf{n}_i\,,
\end{eqnarray}
$R\in SO(3)$ and $t\in \mathbf{R}^3$ are resp. the rotation and translation I am looking for, and $d$ is the distance between two lines, e.g.

\begin{eqnarray}
d(P, \mathbf{m},Q, \mathbf{n}) = \frac{|(P-Q).(\mathbf{n}\times \mathbf{m})|}{\|\mathbf{n}\times \mathbf{m}\|}
\end{eqnarray}

when $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{m}$ are not colinear.

I was wondering if there would be any chance that there exist a closed form formula for this problem, as there is one for the same problem with point sets. However I must admit that even factoring out the translation component, which is easy in the case of point sets, is difficult for me here.

EDIT: in case this sub-problem makes a solution any simpler, we could assume that each line set share a common point, i.e. $P_i = P_j$ and $Q_i=Q_j$, $\forall (i,j)\in\{1,...n\}^2$.